# Destructuring assignments are not supported by current JavaScript version

Tags: webstorm, electron

I followed the steps [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/05/getting-started-with-electron-in-webstorm/) to configure code completion and other stuff in WebStorm but I'm still getting the following syntax errors.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

By changing 'JavaScript language version' (`Settings/Languages & Frameworks/JavaScript`) accordingly, to either '`ECMASCript 6`' or '`JSX Harmony`'. BTW, WebStorm can do it for you: hit `Alt+Enter` on the highlighted statement, choose 'Change JavaScript version to ECMASCript 6' from the popup

Comment: That fixed it, but what does this mean exactly?  What is ECMASCript?